# button_to with image Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby

I want to put an image that works as a button. For the moment I have this:

```
<td><%= button_to '+1', upvote_submission_path(submission), method: :post %></td>
```

This works, however, I don't know how to put an image called grayarrow.gif instead of the "+1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply replace the text with a [`image_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) like this:

```
<td>
  <%= button_to(image_tag('grayarrow.gif').html_safe, 
                upvote_submission_path(submission), 
                method: :post) %>
</td>
```

Comment: Using this it prints: <img src="grayarrow.gif" /> on the button instead of puting the image

Comment: I updated my answer and added the `html_safe` call because otherwise, the `img` tag would be escaped as you already noticed.